# Running chrome extension with keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a very basic knowledge of js and I'm developing a Google Chrome extension. My aim is to create an extension in order to select (highlight) some text and open a popup window with results coming from a query.

This code works perfectly however, I need to open the extension and click on a button to do so. Could you please help me?

Here is the js code

```
/* The function that finds and returns the selected text */
var funcToInject = function() {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = range.cloneContents().textContent;
    return selectedText;
};
/* This line converts the above function to string
 * (and makes sure it will be called instantly) */
var jsCodeStr = ';(' + funcToInject + ')();';

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    /* Find our input elements from `popup.html` */
    var inp = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]#inp');
    var btn = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]#btn');

    /* Open a new tab with the search results */
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var query = encodeURIComponent(inp.value);
        chrome.windows.create({ type: 'popup', height: 600, width:600, url: url + query });
    });

    /* Inject the code into all frames of the active tab */
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: jsCodeStr,
        allFrames: true
    }, function(selectedTextPerFrame) {

        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            /* Report any error */
            alert('ERROR:\n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        } else if ((selectedTextPerFrame.length > 0)
                && (typeof(selectedTextPerFrame[0]) === 'string')) {
            /* The results are as expected, 
             * populate the "search-query" input field */
            inp.value = selectedTextPerFrame[0].trim();
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Extensions can't open their standard popup programmatically in stable Chrome versions. You can create a separate small window via chrome.windows.create or inject a DOM element into the current page (e.g. an iframe with src that points to your extension's page declared in web_accessible_resources).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, do you mean to open the window through the manifest file?